# How to get UTC time with seconds in java?

Tags: java, time

http://time.is/UTC displays correct seconds.

I set my local clock back 5 seconds to test this.
I've tried JodaTime, and this. It's getting my local time.

```
    NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
    TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
    long returnTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();
    Date time = new Date(returnTime);
    System.out.println("Time from " + TIME_SERVER + ": " + time);
```

Output:
Time from time.nist.gov: Mon Apr 20 06:44:20 CDT 2015

Time.IS Output:
6:44:25 AM

I need UTC time down to the second.

Comment: @halex longs can't carry timezone offsets, so as David Wallace said above, it's a local formatting issue because internal values are held in UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new DateTime with UTC as the timezone

```
final DateTime now = new DateTime(returnTime, DateTimeZone.UTC);
final Date javaDate = now.toDate();
```

Comment: I think the idea is to get the time from a NTP server, not from the local machine...

Comment: How to do this using `Date`,  not `DateTime`?

Comment: Until Java 8, the Joda library was far superior to the in-built Java types so I'll answer this in the original question using Joda.

Comment: @SteveChaloner The output is still from the local machine.
Here's what I got:
http://pastebin.com/enK4sWtG
Output:
Time from time-a.nist.gov: Mon Apr 20 11:34:08 CDT 2015
Mon Apr 20 11:34:08 CDT 2015

Still not correct with seconds...

Comment: @Blackie when the DateTime is converted to a java.util.Date the timezone information is lost; see previous point about the built-in Java date support sucking.  If you add `System.out.println(now);` to your code, you'll see it prints in UTC.

Comment: @Blackie to get UTC time instead of local time use `timeInfo.getMessage().getReceiveTimeStamp().getTime()` instead of `timeInfo.getReturnTime()`